# Demuxing a video media file with FFMPEG

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264

After starting this question [Extracting the h264 part of a video file (demuxing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524322/extracting-the-h264-part-of-a-video-file-demuxing) I was actually able to figure out that,

1. When I reverted to an older version of FFMPEG (avcodec-55.dll) as against the avcodec-57.dll I was using earlier, the code worked perfectly without any error and the resultant h264 file played with ffplay.
2. When I tracked my output when using the avcodec-57.dll version of FFMPEG (most recent version), there was actually an error `"Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead"` after the call `avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx_v, NULL)` and another one after the call to `avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx_a, NULL)`. The program continued executing, the audio was fine but the .h264 file wasn't.

The output

```
Press any key to continue . . .
Press any key to continue . . .
Press any key to continue . . .
Press any key to continue . . .

==============Input Video=============
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'sample.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : 10153755968775490
    encoder         : Lavf57.19.100
  Duration: 00:01:07.27, start: 0.020021, bitrate: 1058 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 400x224 [
SAR 199:200 DAR 199:112], 927 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 12
8 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler

==============Output Video============
Output #0, h264, to 'sample.h264':
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 400x224 [SAR 199:200 DAR 199:112],
 q=2-31, 927 kb/s, 30 tbc

==============Output Audio============
Output #0, mp3, to 'sample.mp3':
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s

======================================
[h264 @ 00a3ee20] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer
 is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
[mp3 @ 00a4fec0] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer
is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

extern "C"
{
    #include "libavformat/avformat.h"
}


#define USE_H264BSF 1

int main()
{
    AVOutputFormat *ofmt_a = NULL,*ofmt_v = NULL;
    AVFormatContext *ifmt_ctx = NULL, *ofmt_ctx_a = NULL, *ofmt_ctx_v = NULL;
    AVPacket pkt;
    int ret, i;
    int videoindex=-1,audioindex=-1;
    int frame_index=0;

    const char *in_filename  = "sample.mp4";
    const char *out_filename_v = "sample.h264";
    const char *out_filename_a = "sample.mp3";

    av_register_all();
    //Input
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, in_filename, 0, 0)) < 0) {
        printf( "Could not open input file.");
        goto end;
    }
    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx, 0)) < 0) {
        printf( "Failed to retrieve input stream information");
        goto end;
    }
system("pause");

    //Output
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx_v, NULL, NULL, out_filename_v);
    if (!ofmt_ctx_v) {
        printf( "Could not create output context\n");
        ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
        goto end;
    }
    ofmt_v = ofmt_ctx_v->oformat;

system("pause");

    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx_a, NULL, NULL, out_filename_a);
    if (!ofmt_ctx_a) {
        printf( "Could not create output context\n");
        ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
        goto end;
    }
    ofmt_a = ofmt_ctx_a->oformat;
system("pause");
    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
            //Create output AVStream according to input AVStream
            AVFormatContext *ofmt_ctx;
            AVStream *in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[i];
            AVStream *out_stream = NULL;

            if(ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO){
                videoindex=i;
                out_stream=avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx_v, in_stream->codec->codec);
                ofmt_ctx=ofmt_ctx_v;
            }else if(ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO){
                audioindex=i;
                out_stream=avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx_a, in_stream->codec->codec);
                ofmt_ctx=ofmt_ctx_a;
            }else{
                break;
            }

            if (!out_stream) {
                printf( "Failed allocating output stream\n");
                ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
                goto end;
            }
            //Copy the settings of AVCodecContext
            if (avcodec_copy_context(out_stream->codec, in_stream->codec) < 0) {
                printf( "Failed to copy context from input to output stream codec context\n");
                goto end;
            }
            out_stream->codec->codec_tag = 0;

            if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
                out_stream->codec->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    }
system("pause");
    //Dump Format------------------
    printf("\n==============Input Video=============\n");
    av_dump_format(ifmt_ctx, 0, in_filename, 0);
    printf("\n==============Output Video============\n");
    av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx_v, 0, out_filename_v, 1);
    printf("\n==============Output Audio============\n");
    av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx_a, 0, out_filename_a, 1);
    printf("\n======================================\n");
    //Open output file
    if (!(ofmt_v->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        if (avio_open(&ofmt_ctx_v->pb, out_filename_v, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0) {
            printf( "Could not open output file '%s'", out_filename_v);
            goto end;
        }
    }

    if (!(ofmt_a->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        if (avio_open(&ofmt_ctx_a->pb, out_filename_a, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0) {
            printf( "Could not open output file '%s'", out_filename_a);
            goto end;
        }
    }

    //Write file header
    if (avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx_v, NULL) < 0) {
        printf( "Error occurred when opening video output file\n");
        goto end;
    }

    if (avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx_a, NULL) < 0) {
        printf( "Error occurred when opening audio output file\n");
        goto end;
    }
    system("pause");
#if USE_H264BSF
    AVBitStreamFilterContext* h264bsfc =  av_bitstream_filter_init("h264_mp4toannexb"); 
#endif

    while (1) {
        AVFormatContext *ofmt_ctx;
        AVStream *in_stream, *out_stream;
        //Get an AVPacket
        if (av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &pkt) < 0)
            break;
        in_stream  = ifmt_ctx->streams[pkt.stream_index];


        if(pkt.stream_index==videoindex){
            out_stream = ofmt_ctx_v->streams[0];
            ofmt_ctx=ofmt_ctx_v;
            #if USE_H264BSF
                av_bitstream_filter_filter(h264bsfc, in_stream->codec, NULL, &pkt.data, &pkt.size, pkt.data, pkt.size, 0);
            #endif
            printf("Write Video Packet. size:%d\tpts:%lld\n",pkt.size,pkt.pts);
        }else if(pkt.stream_index==audioindex){
            out_stream = ofmt_ctx_a->streams[0];
            ofmt_ctx=ofmt_ctx_a;
            printf("Write Audio Packet. size:%d\tpts:%lld\n",pkt.size,pkt.pts);
        }else{
            continue;
        }


        //Convert PTS/DTS
        pkt.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.pts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, (AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
        pkt.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.dts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, (AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
        pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(pkt.duration, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base);
        pkt.pos = -1;
        pkt.stream_index=0;
        //Write
        if (av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &pkt) < 0) {
            printf( "Error muxing packet\n");
            break;
        }
        //printf("Write %8d frames to output file\n", frame_index);
        av_free_packet(&pkt);
        frame_index++;
    }
system("pause");
#if USE_H264BSF
    av_bitstream_filter_close(h264bsfc);  
#endif

    //Write file trailer
    av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx_a);
    av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx_v);
end:
    avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx);
    /* close output */
    if (ofmt_ctx_a && !(ofmt_a->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
        avio_close(ofmt_ctx_a->pb);

    if (ofmt_ctx_v && !(ofmt_v->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
        avio_close(ofmt_ctx_v->pb);

    avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx_a);
    avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx_v);

    system("pause");
    if (ret < 0 && ret != AVERROR_EOF) {
        printf( "Error occurred.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT 1**
After reading through http://lists.libav.org/pipermail/libav-devel/2014-June/060048.html, I figured what was causing the `"Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead"`. I fixed it by adding `out_stream->time_base = in_stream->time_base;` before the call to `avformat_write_header`. The code now runs without any error! The h264 file created with the old FFMPEG (avcodec-55.dll) works fine while that created by the recent avcodec-57.dll is still invalid.