# How-to stream H.264 with netcat?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, netcat, raspberry-pi4

I use this command to stream a live video from a Raspberry camera:

```
raspivid -n -ih -t 0 -rot 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 15 -b 1000000 -o - | nc -lkv4 5001
```

I need a way to stream a H.264 file through `netcat` like the example above. It must be received in the same way than my Raspberry camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input file is h264, I guess you can simply pipe the file in netcat:

For instance:

```
cat <yourfile> | nc -lkv4 5001
```

If you need to do some transcoding you can use ffmpeg. For instance from a MP4/FLV file [(see original answer here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19304516/2437450):

```
ffmpeg -i <your file>.flv -vcodec copy -an -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb | nc -lkv4 5001
```

Comment: It's working, thank you! But, the fps are bad... is there any way I can lower the fps so it will stream without any glitz? thanks again

Comment: @roye1233 you can also use ffmpeg to reduce the number of FPS, see the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462731/using-ffmpeg-to-change-framerate/45465730